# WMI Get Object Access Denied

Tags: vbscript, permissions, wmi

1. Regular user logs in to domain
2. Group Policy runs User Configuration -> Logon -> VBS Script
3. Set ServerWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\print\root\CIMV2")
4. I get Access Denied as regular user, works for Domain Admin
5. Tried changing GPO to run with admin parameters - /u:"domain\user" /p:"adminpassword"
6. Tried impersonateLevel=impersonate
7. Tried authenticationLevel=pktPrivacy
8. Tried going to remote machine (print) and changing WMI CIMV2 permissions for Authenticated Users to have all the permissions

Need a non-admin user to run this logon script with sufficient privileges to Remotely query WMI on our print server. I do this to do Client/Server comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

For remote WMI access with explicit credentials you have to use something like this:

```
server = "print"
user   = "domain\admin"
pass   = "password"

Set locator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set svc = locator.ConnectServer(server, "root\cimv2", user, pass)
svc.Security_.ImpersonationLevel = 3
```

I **strongly** advise **against** doing this in any kind of user/login script.

A better approach would be to [enable remote WMI access](https://support.infosim.net/demo/wmi/wmi.html) for the users who need it.

However, note that remote WMI access is usually not allowed for security reasons, so why do you believe you need this? What do you want to accomplish by giving your users remote WMI access?

Comment: My script is used to map printers.

Comment: Our printer sharenames never change (ex 34322)
Our printer names can change (ex HC 02 - 34322 - HP LJ 2055)

Renaming a printer causes my script to add 2 printers for the same printer:
HC 02 - 34322 - HP LJ 2055 (sharename 34322)
HC 04 - 34322 - HP LJ 2055 (sharename 34322)

I need to be able to have regular (non-admin) users be able to query the print server WMI
If Client/Server sharename are same but names are different, it has been renamed, so delete it

Comment: @user1880826 No, you don't. Publish your printers in AD and delete/reconnect them on every logon.

Comment: I'm just a technician. It is the decison of my superior the Network Administrator who has no interest in using that method.

This is out next best option. You seem like you have the understanding I am looking for, are you going to help me?

Comment: @user1880826 Sorry, but I won't assist you with shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: The decision has been made and its not going change. Its not my decision, it is my the decision of my superior.

Stop trying to assess a decision that is made and out of my control and help me with what I can control.